# Angular code mysteriously assigning values

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

This code is assigning the value of 'temps' to this.messages for some reason that I do not understand, any help would be appreciated. I know the issue lies within the below chunk of code as removing the .sort section changes the output order of this.messages.

```
this.currentMessageSubject.subscribe(()=> {
  console.log('Refreshing messages')
  if (this.conversationId) {
    firebase.firestore().collectionGroup('conv').where("parentMessageId", "==", this.conversationId).get().then(async (querySnapshot) => {
      let temps: FirebaseMessages;
      let tempsMsgs = new Map();
      temps = this.messages;
      temps.messages = []
      
      querySnapshot.forEach((newConvo) => {
        const thing = { id: newConvo.id, ...newConvo.data() } as FirebaseMessage;
  
        if (!tempsMsgs.has(thing.id)) {
          tempsMsgs.set(thing.id, thing)
          temps.messages.push(thing);
        }
        
      })
      temps.messages.sort(function(a,b){
        return a.timestamp.seconds - b.timestamp.seconds;
      });
      temps.messages = temps.messages.filter((message) => {
        if (message.id) {
          return true;
        }
        
        return false;
      })
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: Did the answers below solved the problem, or do you still need help to find out what's wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assign a non-primitive value to a variable (i.e. object), it will be passed by reference.

So, in your case this line:

```
temps = this.messages;
```

assigns the same object that is in your `this.messages` to your `temps` variable. So, editing `temps` will actually edit the `this.messages` as well, since both are pointing to the same object.

You will have to clone your object, and assign the clone to your `temps` variable. Regarding cloning - there are multiple good answers about cloning object on SO, so I will not cover that here since we don't know the structure of the `messages`.

Answer (score 0):

When doing `temps = this.messages;`, the reference is passed to `temps`.

You need to clone this object in another way (notice the change line 7) :

```
this.currentMessageSubject.subscribe(()=> {
  console.log('Refreshing messages')
  if (this.conversationId) {
    firebase.firestore().collectionGroup('conv').where("parentMessageId", "==", this.conversationId).get().then(async (querySnapshot) => {
      let temps: FirebaseMessages;
      let tempsMsgs = new Map();
      temps = {...this.messages};
      temps.messages = []
      
      querySnapshot.forEach((newConvo) => {
        const thing = { id: newConvo.id, ...newConvo.data() } as FirebaseMessage;
  
        if (!tempsMsgs.has(thing.id)) {
          tempsMsgs.set(thing.id, thing)
          temps.messages.push(thing);
        }
        
      })
      temps.messages.sort(function(a,b){
        return a.timestamp.seconds - b.timestamp.seconds;
      });
      temps.messages = temps.messages.filter((message) => {
        if (message.id) {
          return true;
        }
        
        return false;
      })
    })
  }
})
```

You can refer to this topic to learn more about this : [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)